# Global keyword on module scope

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a Python file that have the following lines:

```
import sys

global AdminConfig
global AdminApp
```

This script runs on Jython. I understand the use of global keyword inside functions, but what does the use of the "global" keyword on module level mean?

Comment: This post might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python

Comment: What does it mean? Nothing at all. Whoever wrote this code was ignorant or mistaken about what the keyword does.

Comment: Those objects "AdminConfig" and "AdminApp" are implemented by the Webpshere Application Server and this file use them , another question that i have is how they are fullfilled ? The only import is the sys module

Answer (score 1):

`global x` changes the scoping rules for `x` **in current scope** to module level, so when `x` is already at the module level, it serves no purpose.

To clarify:

```
>>> def f(): # uses global xyz
...  global xyz
...  xyz = 23
... 
>>> 'xyz' in globals()
False
>>> f()
>>> 'xyz' in globals()
True
```

while

```
>>> def f2():
...  baz = 1337 # not global
... 
>>> 'baz' in globals()
False
>>> f2() # baz will still be not in globals()
>>> 'baz' in globals()
False
```

but

```
>>> 'foobar' in globals()
False
>>> foobar = 42 # no need for global keyword here, we're on module level
>>> 'foobar' in globals()
True
```

and

```
>>> global x # makes no sense, because x is already global IN CURRENT SCOPE
>>> x=1
>>> def f3():
...  x = 5 # this is local x, global property is not inherited or something
... 
>>> f3() # won't change global x
>>> x # this is global x again
1
```